# Getting PUSH notification from another APP in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

I have an installed **third-party** app from Google Play. This app send push notifications to my phone. How can I do some action (go to some URL, send SMS etc.) where I got any notification from this app?

Comment: is that was your app or it was an third party app?

Comment: This is third party app